# Can't create a Contact John Doe to related Account passing ID, any suggestions?

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous

```
global with sharing class JohnDoeBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    //Start method
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Type, (SELECT Name, LastName FROM Contacts WHERE FirstName != \'John\'\n' +
                'AND LastName != \'Doe\')\n' +
                'FROM Account';
        System.debug('Inside start method');
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    //Execute method
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {
        createCaseTeam();
        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Account.Name, Account.Id
                                  FROM Contact];
        for(Account a : scope) {
            System.debug('Inside first forloop');
            System.debug('You are inside the addContact');
            Contact con = new Contact(FirstName = 'John', LastName = 'Doe');
            con.AccountId = a.Id;
            contacts.add(con);
            //If the account type is Prospect, then create an associated Case
            if(a.Type == 'Prospect') {
                List<Case> casesToAdd = new List<Case>();
                Case c = new Case (
                    Subject = 'John Doe Case'
                );
                casesToAdd.add(c);
                System.debug('You are inside the createCase!');
                /*If the length of the contacts list is more than 1 and there's no John Doe Case,
                then add these contacts to the Case Team*/
                if((a.Contacts.size() > 1) &&
                        (matchContacts() != false) && (matchCases(c) != true)) {
                    //  AddToCaseTeamMethod('John Doe Case', 'testRole1');
                    System.debug('You are inside the AddCaseTeam if, almost done.');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Finish method
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('Hope it\'s fine');
    }
```

I can see the `System.Debug('You are inside the addContact')` but it doesn't add any John Doe Contact to the Accounts in the Account Scope, can someone explain me how I can fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the full code to understand the logic and review? As per given code, I don't able to find "Insert" statement for contact List variable :(

Comment: Sure, I've edited it :) btw I know that DML operations inside loops are a bad procedure, so i was using list and the add() method

Comment: i've made an insert contact; call right after the for loop, but it's giving me this exception " INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]"

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please do not ask the same question multiple times *(ref: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358340/cant-reach-the-third-loop-in-an-execute-method-of-a-batch-apex-class-any-sugge)*. Please choose which of these questions you wish to keep active and receive help on, and delete the other one. Otherwise, one will be selected as a duplicate (most likely this one since it is newer) and closed. To learn more of the SFSE format and culture, take the SFSE [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick for you. We query for accounts with contacts where the contact is john doe, in the iteration, if the account does not have contact we add one.

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {

    createCaseTeam();
    List<Account> accounts = [
            SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Doe')
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id IN :scope
    ];
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    
    for (Account a : accounts) {
        System.debug('Inside first forloop');
        if (a.Contacts.isEmpty()) {
            contacts.add(
                    new Contact(FirstName = 'John', LastName = 'Doe', AccountId = a.Id)
            );
        }
        //If the account type is Prospect, then create an associated Case
        if (a.Type == 'Prospect') {
            List<Case> casesToAdd = new List<Case>();
            Case c = new Case
                    (
                            Subject = 'John Doe Case'
                    );
            casesToAdd.add(c);
            System.debug('You are inside the createCase!');
            /*If the length of the contacts list is more than 1 and there's no John Doe Case,
                then add these contacts to the Case Team*/
            if ((a.Contacts.size() > 1) &&
                    (matchContacts() != false) && (matchCases(c) != true)) {
                //  AddToCaseTeamMethod('John Doe Case', 'testRole1');
                System.debug('You are inside the AddCaseTeam if, almost done.');
            }
        }
    }
    insert contacts;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. I've added "Type" in the accounts SELECT query, now is giving the following DML exception "MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): Contact, original object: CaseTeamTemplate: []" at line 55 (insert contacts;). Do you know how to resolve it?
PS: createCaseTeam method create a new CaseTeamTemplate and insert it

Comment: you need to do what is stated in the error msg, move the case team template creation to different transaction, to the start method for example